# PHP PDO Insert not working with ajax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, pdo

I'm having a really weird issue where i am getting the result of a successful sql insert but the values aren't inserting. I'm trying to create a thumbs up/down system for comments.
the sql is a simple database insert. 
The ajax query is calling a php file which contains a switch. the switch is going on the function variable.

**PHP**

```
case "comment-vote-up":

    $IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $CommentID = $_GET['CommentID'];
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO CommentVotes (IP, CommentID, Vote) VALUES (:IP, :CommentID, :Vote)");
    $array = array(':IP' => $IP, ':CommentID' => $CommentID, ':Vote' => 1);
    if($stmt->execute($array))
    {
        echo '<img src = "../images/site-design/thumb-up-8bit-trans-voted.png"/>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<img src = "../images/site-design/thumb-up-8bit-trans.png"/>';
    }
break;
```

**AJAX**

```
function commentupvote(id)
{
    $.ajax({url:"../scripts/functionsswitch.php?function=comment-vote-up&CommentID=1",success:function(result){
    $("#commentupvote"+id).html(result);
    }});
}
```

i click the thumb image and it will get returned with the sucessful voted thumb image that should only return if te query is successful. ive checked the webservers error logs and it throws nothing. there is no pdo sql exception thrown. im finding it really difficult to debug this.

Comment: Where did `event` come from?

Comment: sorry i forgot to cut that. i was messing around with some other things trying to debug this

Comment: In some browsers, `window.event` is the currently executing event.

Comment: Enable PDO error signalling: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: i think the sql query is fine though. it executs fine if i enter the url that ajax uses into the browser

Comment: @DanHastings maybe the path is wrong? `../scripts/`

Comment: Shouldn't your url be `"../scripts/functionsswitch.php?function=comment-vote-up&CommentID="+id`, as right now every click is for `CommentID=1`.

Comment: but its returning a result. as far as ajax is concerned the it passes successfully because the php is returning the result of a successful sql insert

Comment: Is there a unique index on any of the fields?

Comment: IP address and CommentID are Primary keys but the table is empty. I deleted any rows after the statement executed wen i directly entered the pages url

Comment: im leaning toward this being an sql issue. as far as php is concerned the querys are executing fine. the data just isnt being inserted. if i insert the data and try again the query fails, like it should. so the issue is with the sql

Answer (score 0):

I found out the cause of the issue. I have always written my switch variables this way but i guess it didnt like something about it this time. Ive no idea what went wrong but the issue was with the '-' symbols in the url. It worked fine through the browser, but for some reason the ajax calls did not like this. as soon as i removed the dashes the code worked